# terraform generate map using for loop with two distinct resource inside

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have variable with below input

```
variable functions = ["one", "two"]
```

Im trying to achieve something like this in locals (what my attempt is, included below, or something I hope it would work)

```
locals{
  alarms_with_math_expression = {
    for function in var.functions: 
      "aws_lambda_fn_error-${function}" => {
        alarm_description           = "Error rate has exceeded 60%"
        evaluation_periods          = "2"
        threshold                   = "60"
        metric_query_id             = "Lambda"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "Errors"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "AWS/Lambda"
      },
      "aws_lambda_log_process_error-${function}" => {
        alarm_description           = "Processing error rate has exceeded 40%"
        evaluation_periods          = "1"
        threshold                   = "40"
        metric_query_id             = "LogProcessing"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "LogProcessErrorCount"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "TestLambda"
      }
  }
}
```

Output im trying to generate, a 4 member map, as below, so that I can use for_each with creating alarms in resource section

```
{
"aws_lambda_fn_error-one" = {
        alarm_description           = "Error rate has exceeded 60%"
        evaluation_periods          = "2"
        threshold                   = "60"
        metric_query_id             = "Lambda"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "Errors"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "AWS/Lambda"
 },
"aws_lambda_log_process_error-one" => {
        alarm_description           = "Processing error rate has exceeded 40%"
        evaluation_periods          = "1"
        threshold                   = "40"
        metric_query_id             = "LogProcessing"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "LogProcessErrorCount"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "TestLambda"
 },
"aws_lambda_fn_error-two" = {
        alarm_description           = "Error rate has exceeded 60%"
        evaluation_periods          = "2"
        threshold                   = "60"
        metric_query_id             = "Lambda"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "Errors"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "AWS/Lambda"
 },
"aws_lambda_log_process_error-two" => {
        alarm_description           = "Processing error rate has exceeded 40%"
        evaluation_periods          = "1"
        threshold                   = "40"
        metric_query_id             = "LogProcessing"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "LogProcessErrorCount"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "TestLambda"
 },
}
```

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "generic_alarms" {
  for_each = var.environment == "prod" ? local.alarms_with_math_expression : {}

  alarm_name          = each.key
  alarm_description   = each.value.alarm_description
  .
  .
}
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `flatten` and `...` (argument expansion):

```
locals{
  alarms_with_math_expression = merge(flatten([
    for function in var.functions: 
     [ {"aws_lambda_fn_error-${function}" = {
        alarm_description           = "Error rate has exceeded 60%"
        evaluation_periods          = "2"
        threshold                   = "60"
        metric_query_id             = "Lambda"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "Errors"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "AWS/Lambda"
      }},
      {"aws_lambda_log_process_error-${function}" = {
        alarm_description           = "Processing error rate has exceeded 40%"
        evaluation_periods          = "1"
        threshold                   = "40"
        metric_query_id             = "LogProcessing"
        metric_to_compare_name      = "LogProcessErrorCount"
        metric_to_compare_namespace = "TestLambda"
      }}]
  ])...)
}
```

Comment: @Danny No problem. Let me know hot it will go.

Comment: You are a king of expressions!!. I can generate plan output without error. That works :-)